# Have ViewController appear only on first launch

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to have my viewController named "DoctorInformationController" appear only when the user launches the app for the first time. Ive seen some people's answers, however i would like to know how to do this in swift please!

Thank you

Comment: I would use a preference in `NSUserDefaults` to track whether the sheet has been shown before. You can decide to show the sheet in your app delegate, method applicationDidFinishLaunching()

Comment: Okay! Would you mind answering the question with some sample code?

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist If you've found an answer could you mark one as best or show how you did the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to tell if it's the first launch built into the UIKit framework, however you can do it another way.

In AppDelegate.swift, go to applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (the first one, usually). Now, add this:

```
//Check for key "first_launch" in User Defaults
if let _ = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("first_launch") {

    //Set your own global variable to be true. Then, when your ViewController 
    //loads, do a popup window with that DoctorViewController thingy if the
    //variable is true
    //Example:
    isFirstLaunch = true

    //Then, set "first_launch" to be a value so your app will never call this block again 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("", forKey: "first_launch")

}
```

Comment: why not use `setBoolForKey:`?

Comment: @nielsbot It doesn't matter, as long as something is there. I'm not checking if it's true, I'm checking if it exists. Same difference, right?

Comment: I added this and i seem to get an error on the if statement saying: "initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'string' ". How can i fix this, sorry new to swift!

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist Sorry, I did a typo. Replace `as! String` with `as? String`. I'm making an edit to the answer now

Comment: You could leave off the `as? String`

Comment: @nielsbot Yeah, you could, I guess it looks neater too. I'll make the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This code I use that will launch a viewcontoller based on first or second launch of the app.

**This in the AppDelegate.**

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


  let firstLaunch = defaults.boolForKey("FirstLaunch")

  if firstLaunch  {
    print("Not first launch.")

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navController") as! UINavigationController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


  } else {
    print("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstrunVCstoryboard") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  }

  return true
}
```

You would need to adapt it to fit your storyboard and viewcontrollers names.

**EDIT:**

This how I set the value in the first view controller to indicate that first run has completed. So that it will not show again.

```
 self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
```

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you! Is this code adjusted to run on the second launch? Because i just need it for the first and thats it.

Comment: It runs every time and if the first launch has been recored then it loads the  viewcontroller for the second launch.  I use this format so that I can trigger the first launch screens durning an update if some thing needs to be reviewed.